# .NET Framework 1.1 program doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, .net-framework

About a week ago, I installed a program called Microsoft Transliteration Utility. It failed to install at first, asking me to install .NET Framework 1.1, which I did, and I used the program just fine for a while. But now, when launching it, it shows up on the task bar, but the window itself doesn't. I tried compatibility options, and also reinstalled both the program and .NET Framework, but that didn't change anything. Is there something I can do to solve this? I would gladly use a more up-to-date tool, but this is the only one (that I found), that allows me to crate my own transliteration table.

Comment: Did you install [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=33)?

Comment: No, but like I said, I used the application just fine. I'll try try that now, though.

Comment: .NET 1.1 has been removed from Windows 10. Trying to force it to install is not a good idea. You need an upgraded program.

Comment: I didn't force anything, I installed it like normal. Also, I removed software rec tag, bc the description said it's off-topic here. However, I would gladly use a different application, that's either compatible with MTU's tms files, or provides different means of setting up a custom template.

Comment: I perhaps used the wrong word. .NET 1 does not natively appear in Windows 10, and the installation you used may not have completed properly.

Comment: @harrymc that didn't change anything.

Comment: @John Both the main and the SP1 installers finished successfully, no error messages, AND I used this program for several days about a week ago.

Comment: I just downloaded `TransliterationUtility.msi`, I extracted the files without running the MSI. `TransliterationUtility.exe` runs just fine without doing anything. I have .NET 4 and .NET 3.5 but no 1.1 on my Windows 10 machine. It is using files in `C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Well, that could be my problem, because I don't have that https://imgur.com/JGXQ8wn

Comment: I think this is just Windows Explorer trying to be smart and not displaying the real content, open a PowerShell and type: `ls C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32`

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer possible to install .NET Framework 1.1 on Windows 10.
I'm not sure how it did work for you, but evidently it doesn't any longer.

I suggest first to install .NET Framework 3.5 by entering in the Start menu
"Windows Features" and starting *Turn Windows features on or off*.

Click on the check box for ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)"
so it shows a "V" mark, click OK, and reboot if prompted.

This version includes .NET Framework 2.0, the release that followed the
.NET Framework 1.1, and it might be enough to run your program.

If not, you will need to create an installation for .NET 1.1 SP1.
As it is destined to be installed on computers that already have .NET 1.1,
you will need to create an installation that includes both .NET 1.1 SP1 and
.NET 1.1 SP1.
First uninstall the .Net 1.1 software you have installed.

See the article
[Install Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 on Windows 10](https://techjourney.net/install-microsoft-net-framework-1-1-on-windows-10-8-7-vista-fix-regsvcs-exe-error/)
for the steps to follow. Below is a summary of the procedure:

- Create a new folder `C:\DotNet` (or choose another name)
- Download into the folder
  [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=262D25E3-F589-4842-8157-034D1E7CF3A3&displaylang=en).
  The setup file should be saved as `dotnetfx.exe`.
- Download into the folder
  [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a8f5654f-088e-40b2-bbdb-a83353618b38&displaylang=en).
  Save the file as `dotnetfxsp1.exe`.
- Open Command Prompt as Administrator
- Change to the directory : `cd C:\DotNet`
- Run the following commands clicking “Yes” when prompted :

  ```
  dotnetfx.exe /c:"msiexec.exe /a netfx.msi TARGETDIR=C:\DotNet"

  dotnetfxsp1.exe /Xp:C:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp

  msiexec.exe /a c:\DotNet\netfx.msi /p c:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp
  ```
- Run the installation program `netfx.msi` created by the above steps,
  which contains the slipstreamed Service Pack 1.

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 is installed, but MTU installer still failed to run, I tried extracting the installer, but MTU itself didn't run, until I installed .Net Framework 1.1. Also, I will try the steps provided in that article, however, it describes an error, that I did not encounter when installing .Net Framework.

Comment: Didn't work. The last command fails with Error 1310 and Error 1304 (Error writing to file).

Comment: NVM, I'm just dumb. The procedure itself works, But there's no difference. MTU runs, shows up on the task bar, but the window itself does not show up.

Comment: You could set in the Properties of the `.exe` file the Compatibility to XP.

Comment: I tried that, and others, too. No luck.

Comment: Will it show up if you Shift-right-click it on the taskbar and set to Maximise?

Comment: Oh.. it does! But restoring makes it invisible again...

Comment: Something went wrong with the program itself. Try to maximize it and reboot. If it still doesn't work right, uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/), search the disk for any left-over folders of it, then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's working now, but I'm not sure what fixed it. All I did was I Shift-Right-Clicked on the taskbar icon, suggested by @harrymc and I also used a program .NET Framework Cleanup Tool to completely uninstall .NET 1.1, following @PeterHahndorf's comment. And now it just works, like before...

Answer (score 0):

contrary to some comments here, the runtime installers for Dotnet 1.1 and 1.0 absolutely do not include the MFC, MSVCP or MSVCR 70 or 71 files, these libraries are meant to be shipped with the application.

The only folks who had these files installed, were those who had Visual Studio 2003/.Net installed which placed these files for some reason.